# Solving a PDE with Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, animation

Please consider the following Korteweg deVries (KDV) equation:

$\qquad u_t+6uu_t+u_{xxx}=0$

D.J Korteweg & G. de Vries (1882) devised this partial differential equation to account for certain solitary hydraulic waves first noted by John Scott Russell in 1834. Notice that it is the middle term ($6\,u\,u_t$) that contributes the non-linearity, and causes it to be that solutions are not again solutions.

Use the derivative operator `D` to demonstrate that every function of the form

$\qquad u(x,t;b)=2\,b^2\textrm{sech}^2(b\,x-4\,b^3\,t)$

where $b$ is arbitrary, gives a particular solution of the KDV equation.

Animate (with $0\leq t\leq 4$) the superimposed graphs of

$\qquad u(x,t,1)$  and $u(x,t,1,\sqrt{2})$: $-4\leq x\leq 20$

Notice that

1. each wave preserves its shape as it moves (that's why such
   waves are called **Solitons**);
2. the amplitude is coupled to the wave speed (tall and narrow waves move faster than shorter and broader waves)

Comment: show your code please!

Comment: I don't even know how to start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this site does not work like this. But I was curious about this exercise, so plotted it. Since I have the code now, I thought it would not harm to share it. I suggest you consult the documentation on symbols that you don't understand (hightlight unknown symbol and press <kbd>F1</kbd>).

```
u = {x, t, b} \[Function] 2 b^2 Sech[b x - 4 b^3 t]^2;

D[u[x, t, b], t] + 6 u[x, t, b] D[u[x, t, b], x] + D[u[x, t, b], {x, 3}] // Simplify

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  {u[x, t, 1] + u[x, t, Sqrt[2]]},
  {x, -4, 20},
  PlotRange -> {0, 6}
  ],
 {t, 0, 4}
 ]
```